# datagrid checkbox checked status

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, checkbox, itemtemplate

Hi how can we get checkbox checked status when I click submit button with a datagrid?

checkbox is with in the template column like

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgEmp" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="8pt" 
GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                         HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="heading" CellSpacing="2"
                                            Font-Names="Arial">
```

I'm working with Asp.net
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop grid rows and get the checkbox from each row to get its check/uncheck status.
Follow this for more info. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7629/Using-CheckBoxes-within-the-DataGrid-control-to-se

Comment: but here how do I get my bound column value? I want to know the empId of selected row